Деплой телеграм бота с nginx
Хочу задейплойтить телеграм бота и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: я арендовал VPS сервер и установил на него nginx (Конфиг nginx на скрине1). После запуска бота, поступают апдейты, но бот не отвечает
В логах nginx видно, чтобы запросы приходят, но завершаются ошибкой (скрин2)

Результат getWebhookInfo на скрине 3



Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Во-первых, все тексты должны быть текстами, а не скриншотами. Во-вторых, проверьте error.log в логах того же nginx
